# Linear regression - trend line with pgfplots 2

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Happy new year.

I have fitted a trend line of a population-year data with pgfplots. But I get wrong values of slope *m* and intercept *b*. By LibreOffice Calc, I got the values: *f(x)* = 4,478.87 *x* – 8,966,996.64 (and also by the regression online tool  http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/linear-regression/).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
2007 19348
2008 23457
2009 32624
2010 34270
2011 46888
2012 45224
2013 53556
2014 55007
2015 49664
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\datatable};
\addplot [thick, red] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}
] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{\datatable};
\addlegendentry{$y(x)$}
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \; x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: trend line with wrong regression parameters]

If I change the X range of 2007-2015 to 1-9 (i.e., if I move the plot to the left), the slope and intercept results are OK.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
1 19348
2 23457
3 32624
4 34270
5 46888
6 45224
7 53556
8 55007
9 49664
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\datatable};
\addplot [thick, red] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}
] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{\datatable};
\addlegendentry{$y(x)$}
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \; x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: trend line with OK regression parameters]

How could I to fix this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is pushing the limits of the PGF math parser precision. You could instead use `gnuplot` as a backend to do the fitting:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
X Y
2007 19348
2008 23457
2009 32624
2010 34270
2011 46888
2012 45224
2013 53556
2014 55007
2015 49664
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=outer north east,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
    legend cell align=left
]
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {data.dat};
\addlegendentry{Data}

\addplot +[raw gnuplot, thick, red, mark=none, smooth] gnuplot {
    FIT_LIMIT=1.e-14;
    f(x)=a*x+b;
    fit f(x) 'data.dat' using 1:2 via a,b;
    % Next, plot the function using the x positions from the table
    plot 'data.dat' using 1:(f($1))
    set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into$
    print a,b;
       };     
\addlegendentry[]{\pgfplotstableread{parameters.dat}\parameters% Open the file Gnuplot wrote
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\parameters \edef\paramA{\pgfplotsretval}% Get first element, save into \paramA
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of\parameters \edef\paramB{\pgfplotsretval}% Get second element, save into \paramB
     $\pgfmathprintnumber{\paramA} x \pgfmathprintnumber{\paramB}$    
}  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Having encountered this before, I would call it a bug, and a very serious one.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn: In that case, it would probably be good if you could [open a bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/)

Comment: Dear Jake,

I have installed the external package gnuplot. In tex file directory

Comment: I get the following error message at 38 line: `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file '.gnuplotregression.tex.pgf-plot.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.`
So, I installed the external package gnuplot.

Comment: Then, by console: `pdflatex -shell-escape gnuplotregression.tex`.
Then, I get the following message: `"gnuplotregression.pgf-plot.gnuplot", line 2: ';' expected 
! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'parameters.dat'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try ``row sep=crcr'` `and terminate your lines with` `\\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).`
Am I forgetting some step?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you call `gnuplot gnuplotregression.pgf-plot.gnuplot`? Could you post the content of that file?

Comment: @Jake, Before to install `gnuplot` package, I got the plot OK, with wrong regression parameters (NaNxNaN). After of my prior comment, I pressed Enter key after the error message, and I executed `pdflatex -shell-escape gnuplotregression.tex` a second time, with a entire and OK compilation. 
The content of  `gnuplotregression.pgf-plot.gnuplot` is: `set table "TP336-2015-2.pgf-plot.table"; set format "%.5f"
set format "%.7e";; FIT_LIMIT=1.e-14; f(x)=a*x+b; fit f(x) 'data.dat' using 1:2 via a,b; plot 'data.dat' using 1:(f($1)); set print "parameters.dat"; print a,b;`

Comment: PD: I changed the filename to: `TP336-2015-2.tex`. 
I use Gummi as LaTeX editor (changes of the document are immediately visible in the preview screen). With `gnuplot`, the compilation inside Gummi produces  the error explained in my comment of 2016-01-01 14:25:06Z. So, I had to compile by console (`pdflatex -shell-escape gnuplotregression.tex`). Could I to compile the document inside Gummi?

Comment: Dear @Jake, excuse me, do you have any suggestion?